# PHPunit Zend framework 2 Failed asserting response code "302", actual status code is "200"

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

Do the data we try to insert actually inserted when trying with unit testing.

$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\health360\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml

←[41;37mF←[0m.........

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Failed asserting response code "302", actual status code is "200"

C:\xampp\htdocs\health360\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Test\P
HPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase.php:418
C:\xampp\htdocs\health360\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumController
Test.php:73

I am following the official zend framework documentation

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html

What might be the issue

Comment: Can you also share your testIndexActionCanBeAccessed method from AlbumControllerTest class?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your indexActionController please;

Comment: Asserting 302 ? do you have any redirection at the end of your action ? If you are following ZF2 tutorial, indexAction return code 200, addAction, updateAction, deleteAction may return 302 after valid form post